# First letter is capital letter

Tags: google-apps-script

Help, please, I'm programming in google Script and I'm not getting to do the following: Leave the first capital letter, eg.

Only got together words using

> var pagename = projectname.replace (/ \ s / g,'');

When pagename to get "my first project", it's got, myfirstproject, but I'd like that first letter is capital letter, that is, "Myfirstprocect with the letter m in capital letter, "M".

But let missing the first letter is capital Letter . Could anyone help me?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I assume this is not GWT since you have used **var** to declare the variables. There can be various ways to do this in javascript. one way is

```
var newpagename = pagename.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + pagename.slice(1);
```

Comment: Tks Guy. It's perfect.